# Python3 bisect_left: return value does not match the Python documentation description

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

My codes are as follows:

```
import bisect
a = [186, 186, 150, 200, 160, 130, 197, 200]
print("left",bisect.bisect_left(a,150))
```

The return value is: **0**

But as specified in the [document](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/bisect.html) of Python 3.9:

> If x is already present in a, the insertion point will be before (to the left of) any existing entries.

150 exists in the list "a", so the return value should be **1** `(i.e., a.index(150) - 1)`, but the actual returned value is **0** .
Would you please explain the reason?

Comment: Also from the docs: "This module provides support for maintaining *a list in sorted order* without having to sort the list after each insertion." The list ``[186, 186, 150, 200, 160, 130, 197, 200]`` is not sorted.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for your comments, but if the `list a` is not ordered, for a given value `x`, does the function `bisect.bisect_left` randomly return the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bisect` module and generally the underlying [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) is made for *sorted* data. For unsorted data, the result is effectively arbitrary.

For the `bisect_left` algorithm sorted-ness means the algorithm does not have to check for equality: In a sequence `a` the position `i` "to the left" of any existing `x` is the one where `a[i] < x` and `x <= a[i + 1]`. This is because sorted-ness enforces `a[j] <= a[j+1]`.
As such, technically the insertion point will be before (to the left of) any existing entries equal *or larger* than `x`. Sorted-ness guarantees that this is before any existing entries of `x`.

For the sequence `[186, 186, 150, 200, 160, 130, 197, 200]` and `x=150`, the insertion point is `0` because:

- The list is initially bisected into `[186, 186, 150, 200]` and `[160, ...]`.
- The head of the right bisect is equal or larger than `x`; *assuming sorted'ness*, there cannot be a value smaller than `x` in it.
- All values in the left bisect are equal or larger than `x`; *assuming sorted'ness*, the insertion point must be before all of them.

The only point before all values of the left bisection is `0`.